# What is Java module jdk.editpad?

Tags: java, jshell, editpad

The JDK ships with a module `jdk.editpad` that [exports no services or packages](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.editpad/module-summary.html). The Javadoc describes this module as:

> Provides the implementation of the edit pad service used by jdk.jshell.

But if you look at [the modules depended on by `jdk.jshell`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.jshell/module-summary.html), `jdk.editpad` does not appear in the picture.

**So what is `jdk.editpad`, what does it do, and where is it documented?**

Answer (score 1):

`jdk.editpad` is a really small module that provides a simple Swing-based GUI text editor.

[Here's the code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.editpad/share/classes/jdk/editpad) if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: I deleted your commentary. Answering your own Question in not only allowed, doing so is encouraged on Stack Overflow.